# How to use multiple layout within a SailsJS app?

Tags: layout, ejs, sails.js

My Sails.js application have separate `frontend` and `admin` layout.
My view engine is `ejs`.

How do I use separate layouts for frontend and admin site?

Can I use specific layout for each action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Sails.js Documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/views):

At least in EJS, instead of indicating your custom layout with the layout local, you must use _layoutFile:

```
res.view({
  _layoutFile: 'relativePathToYourCustomLayoutFromTheTargetView.ejs'
});
```

The path to the layout you're wanting to use should be specified relative to the view you're rendering. So if you're in the create action of the UserController, rendering a view (views/user/create.ejs), the relative path to your custom layout might be: `../staticSiteLayout.ejs`

```
PROJECT FOLDER
└── views
    ├── staticSiteLayout.ejs
    ├── layout.ejs
    └── user
        └── create.ejs
```

**UPDATE:**

Seems like the documentation is a bit off from the code, so for the current (v0.9.8) version the way to go is the following:

```
module.exports = { 
  index: function(req, res){
    res.view({ layout: 'layoutadmin' });
  }
}
```

Comment: I try this but seems like it doesn't work. This is my code: `module.exports = {
 index: function(req, res){
  res.view({
    _layoutFile: '../layoutadmin.ejs'
  });
 }
}`

Comment: It always renders default layout that I defined in config/views.js

Comment: Could you try `module.exports = { index: function(req, res){ res.view({ layout: 'layoutadmin' }); } }`? Despite the docs, [what they have in the code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/lib/hooks/views/index.js#L268) seems like a more appropriate way to manage the layouts.

Comment: It worked like a charm! It should be updated on the main answer as well as on the SailsJS documentation. Thank you, Mr @bredikhin!

Comment: @anhnt Updated. Just to make sure, you're using the latest stable release (0.9.8), right?

Comment: Thanks @bredikhin, we'll update that in the docs.  You're exactly right, you'll want to set a local `layout` variable to the string name/path of the layout.  This is consistent in v0.10 as well.

Comment: It would be nice if there were support for different layouts having different sets of asset files associated with them.  I can probably do it by duplicating all of the asset pipeline grunt task configurations, but doing that for every layout is suboptimal.

Answer (score 3):

In Sails 0.10 you can set a different layout like this in your controller:

```
// override the layout to use another
    res.locals.layout = 'layouts/layout2';
    return res.view('test');
```

Detailed explanation [here](http://lift.pressmist.com/use-different-layout-sails-js).

Answer (score 2):

In Sails v0.12, if you need to set layout in your controller, you might create a new folder (e.g. "layout") and push layout files.

```
res.view('auth/login', {layout: layout/my_file_layout}
```

you can also do:

```
res.locals.layout = "layout/my_file_layout";
res.view('auth/login');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for spamming your question but i need a similar solution for my app. It would be wonderful to define layouts in **routes.js** so for example /admin/* would use one layout, and eg. /app/* would use the other, etc. Because it's a pita do dive into controllers and overspam them with static layout paths. I tried this concept but it seems to be working only if I also define a controller in the **routes.js** config file eg:

```
module.exports.routes = {

   '/admin/*' : {
      controller: 'AdminController',
      action: 'index',
      locals: {
         layout: 'admin/layout'
      }
   }
};
```

This does work, but is routing all actions for admin into the same controller, which is of course wrong. If I omit the controller part, that concept is always using the default view/layout.ejs and the local is not set:

```
module.exports.routes = {

   '/admin/*' : {
      locals: {
         layout: 'admin/layout'
      }
   }
};
```

This doesn't work but it would be ideal to get it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set view AND layout in your controller (Sails v0.11):

```
res.view('auth/login', { layout: null } );
```

**Layout:**

null = None

'folder/layout' = Your Layout